# 3D transform of things inside SVG working in Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: css, svg, 3d, transform

The " transform-style: preserve-3d;" is working in Firefox -- the transforms are indeed non-affine. But in Chrome, the animation is simple 2D and affine.

http://cs.sru.edu/~ddailey/svg/XYZrot3D2.svg

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau The question is: is this a Chrome bug or is there something I can do to make the non-affine transformations work in Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a Chrome bug. Non-affine transforms, such as 3D transforms, are defined by the [CSS Transforms Module Level 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/).  The requirement to follow that specification is part of the in-development SVG2 standard.  It is not required by the current SVG1.1 standard.

So the fact that Firefox supports it now is a bonus.  I'm sure Chrome will support it eventually also.

Comment: Thanks. I did see an example of some pages where CSS 3D transforms were working with HTML content in Chrome. That's what got me curious about why not SVG?